# With MySQL how to distinguish between a NULL value and a non-existent value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

For example there is a main table:

```
+----+---------+
| Id | column1 |
+----+---------+
|  1 | a       |
|  2 | b       |
|  3 | c       |
+----+---------+
```

And a second table to join with:

```
+----+---------+
| Id | column2 |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Value   |
|  2 | NULL    |
+----+---------+
```

column2 contains string values, but the NULL value here is of type NULL, not a string of 'NULL'.

So what I want to achieve after a joining of two tables is a table like this:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| Id | column1 | column2     |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 | a       | Value       |
|  2 | b       | Null Value  |
|  3 | c       | Not Exist   |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

Is there a possible way with MySQL to distinguish between a NULL value in a column and a column that does not exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    m.Id, m.column1,
    CASE WHEN s.Id IS NULL 
             THEN 'Not Exists'
         WHEN s.column2 IS NULL
             THEN 'Null Value'
         ELSE s.column2
    END AS column2
FROM 
    mainTable AS m
  LEFT JOIN
    secondTable As s
      ON s.Id = m.Id ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe175/4)**